# Yii CTimestampBehavior NOW()

Tags: yii

Использую CTimestampBehavior. 
После сохранения модели ($model->save()) в соответствующем поле остаётся значение "NOW()". 
Как получить значение проставленного в БД времени?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOW()` - это и есть функция которая возвращает текущее время СУБД (в MySQL точно, за другие СУБД не знаю).

`CTimestampBehavior` - умное поведение. Если этот бихевиор подвешен на поля с типами `datetime`, `timestamp` или `date` то он сам автоматом будет подставлять `NOW()`. Если какой-то другой тип поля, например `INT`, то будет использоваться php-функция `time()`.

Кроме того, можно использовать свое переопределенное выражение, которое задается через `CTimestampBehavior::$timestampExpression`.

Например с php-кодом

```
'timestampExpression' => 'time()'
```

или с функцией MySQL

```
'timestampExpression' => new CDbExpression('NOW()')
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это ответ не на мой вопрос :)

Если в PK auto_increment записать NULL и сохранить -- вставленное значение из БД подтягивается в модель AR Yii.

NOW() проставляет в БД значение текущего времени -- как мне в Yii узнать какое значение проставилось?

Comment: После удачного `$model->save()` сделать `$model->refresh()`.

C PK auto_increment ситуация другая, там значение определяется через lastInsertID.